# Converting displayName string to timezone in Java

Tags: java, android, regex, datetime, timezone

I am writing a calendar app in android and have to deal with timezones. One of the server is exchange and returns string like follow:

```
(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West
(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris
...
```

Could you please advise the best way to convert the string above to a Java TimeZone?
The solution I see is to write a mapping table to map to Java timezone IDs or to regexp on the UTC+/-hh:mm pattern.

Comment: Look into SimpleDateFormat: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: When it comes to time & timezones, display names are mostly irrelevant and simply there for human consumption. Are you sure the exchange server doesn't provide any formalised date/time fields using something like ISO8601 formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach comes to mind: use the timezone as the identifier. This isn't perfect, since it'll give you only a `TimeZone` with the same timezone. But it's a start.

Something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("UTC([+\-]\d):\d\d");
Matcher tagMatch = pattern.matcher(sourceString);
while (tagMatch.find()) {
    String parsed = parseTag(tagMatch.group(1);
    TimeZone t= TimeZone.getTimeZone(String.format("Etc/GMT%s", parsed));
}
```

This constructions an ID like `Etc/GMT+3` or `Etc/GMT-11`, which is valid according to [this list](http://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/).

Ideally, the timezone ID can be something like `Europe/Brussels`, but it sounds like you don't have enough information to get the full identifier -- only the actual GMT offset.

Standard disclaimer: code may not compile, I didn't test it, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i did, and i do not really like it. For the time being, I built a hashmap based on that: http://product.ilinc.com/help/webservices/Web_Service_Methods_v2/ConvertTimeZone.htm

Comment: I don't see a better solution than this, given that you don't have a timezone ID. You just have a city name. That's not enough. Even then, the GMT offset would be the same.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Additionally, consider using the same technique with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which has its own [time zone list](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) and time zone objects.

Comment: I created a complete hashmap that maps to Java Default timezone IDs. Ultimately, i do something similar than you code. Not ideal, but thanks.